# Binary search program in python won't stop looping

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, binary-search

I am trying to do a binary search on a list/array, if a given value is provided.
Here is my code:

```
item = "dog"
list = ["banana","dog","apple","britain","light","error","brother"]
length = len(list)
guess = (length + 1) // 2
counter = 0
while list[guess] != item:
    counter = counter + 1
    print("False")
    if guess < list.index(item):
        for i in range(guess):
            del list[i]
    else:
        largest = list[-1]
        for i in range(guess, list.index(largest)):
            del list[i]
    length = len(list)
    guess = (length + 1) // 2
print(f"I found {list[guess]} and it took {counter} tries.")
```

I want it to perform a binary search on my list for the word "dog" but it gets stuck in limbo and just loops and prints false continuously. I'm not sure why.

If someone could correct my code and tell me what's wrong that'd be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Binary search only makes sense on a sorted list. You should probably call the `sort` method on your list before searching it. It's also a very bad idea to name your own variable `list`, since that shadows the name of the builtin `list` type.

Comment: This is an algorithm to find the index of some item, I dont see the point of using the index of that item as part of the algorithm `if guess < list.index(item)`

Comment: I agree with @Jose - you should not be using `list.index(item)` in a search algorithm. I am not sure you understand the algorithm that you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function to do the bs and I was going to just answer the question but now I think it will be better to tell you how you are supposed to do a binary search.

Let `my_list = [2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 5]` and our item `5`. In order to do a binary search we first need to sort the list, so in our case `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

You need to track two positions, we will call them `lo` and `hi` which stands for low and high. We initialize `lo = 0` and `hi = len(my_list) - 1`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 l              h
 0              5
```

Then we compute the middle of the two as `mid = (hi+lo) // 2` in this case `mid = 2`. (`a//b` is the same as `math.floor(a/b)`)

We compare now the item (`5`) with `my_list[mid]` (`3`) and our item is greater so we know that the position of the item has to be higher than `mid` so we can say that `lo = mid + 1`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          l     h
          3     5
```

We recompute `mid = (lo + hi // 2)` and `mid = 4`. We compare `my_list[mid]` (`5`) with item (`5`) and we can know that the index of the item is `mid`.

This explanation is vague and you must think about if you should do `lo = mid + 1` or only `lo = mid`, what happens when the item is lower than the mid, what happens when the item is not in the list. But since you are studying this, I let you think about it.

Hope it helps!